Page loads in Chrome but loads then blanks in Safari
I have noticed a weird issue with some of my pages. They load absolutely fine in Chrome but if I load in Safari, the page loads and shows itself then suddenly 'crashes' to a white page. I can't see any obvious error that is causing the issue. Wondering if anyone has any ideas on what could be the issue.
Link

Surely you don't expect anyone to click a random link here. You should just paste relevant code.
